# How does Facebook comment box work without input tag?

Tags: html, css, facebook, input

I was inspecting facebook's comment box and it was surprising to me that there is no input tag, just a lot of nested div.

Anyone with the knowledge on how it's being implemented and why is that a better approach than a simple input tag?

[here the screen screenshot of me inspecting the comment box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SE0h.png)

thank you in advance

Comment: It is from Facebook SDK

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully its `contenteditable`, Obviously with some script, validations, programming ...

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Am I a input ???</div>
```

Comment: You hope how it works, so therefore, that is how it works? If one hopes that your answer is correct, will that make it so? 

How does Facebook's comment box work without an input element?